# How to exclude my domain from referrals?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using Google Analytics with Google Tag Manager.

In the Acquisition > Channels > Referral , I can see our domain:

[image]

The website domain exists in the Tracking Infos Excluded list, but still I can see the domain inside Referrals.

How can I totally exclude the domain from the referrals?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at filters in the Admin section of Google analytics?
You can create filters at the account level or view label. Choose the "exclude" filter for your domain name in "referral" field.

Keep in mind that it will apply the filter for the data it collects from that point on, not on the existing data retroactively.